# Reactive Native Web: Open linked PDF from Webview within the App

Tags: android, react-native, pdf, react-native-webview

Is there an easy way to open/display a PDF which is linked on a website shown via WebView within react-native-webview within the App or at least within the default PDF app on the phone?

How to "change" behaviour of the website, right now a linked PDF (e.g. `<a href="http://www.example.com/bla.pdf">Link</a>` is opened in the normal browser and than downloaded... instead it should just open up.

I found react-native-pdf and react-native-view-pdf but they seem to simply open local PDFs... How to actually inject and modify links ON the website to have that behaviour?

Thanks

EDIT:
What I tried is:

import Pdf from 'react-native-pdf';

```
showPdf(pdfurl) {
  const source = {uri: pdfurl,cache:true};
  //const source = require('./test.pdf');  // ios only
  //const source = {uri:'bundle-assets://test.pdf'};

  //const source = {uri:'file:///sdcard/test.pdf'};
  //const source = {uri:"data:application/pdf;base64,..."};

  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Pdf
            source={source}
            onLoadComplete={(numberOfPages,filePath)=>{
                console.log(`number of pages: ${numberOfPages}`);
            }}
            onPageChanged={(page,numberOfPages)=>{
                console.log(`current page: ${page}`);
            }}
            onError={(error)=>{
                console.log(error);
            }}
            style={styles.defaults.pdf} />
      </View>
  )
}
```

Within the Webview config:

```
          onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={(event) => {
            if (event.url.includes('.pdf')) {
              this.showPdf(event.url);
              return false;
            }
            return true;
          }}
```

Comment: I want to use to in a customer portal, the customer will upload his own PDFs, so no security thread. How to change the website within the webview to accomplish this?

Comment: See, I load a customer portal using WebView, hence the HTML is unmodified at first while loading. And I really dont know how to re-route the linked PDFs into a local 3rd party app. Could you give me a buzzword where to start?